# Power BI tabular report - Display rows that have duplicates across other rows within a group

Tags: powerbi

I am very new to Power BI and am finding my way around, and am struggling with this problem.

[I have a dataset as below that has EMployee First Name , Last Name, Site , Employee ID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoJUk.png)

[I want to have a tablular listing of Employees with same First Name and Last Name, but within a Site  , so this data can be reviewed by the administrator to look out for possible duplicate data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcY2A.png)

In SQL ,I would group the data by **Site , EmpFName, EmpLName** and display all rows where count(*) > 1

[Below is what I want to display in my Power Bi tabular report , the 4 rows where the same First Name, Last Name are found in a given site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETh7n.png)

Also, my employee dataset is close to 500K rows .

Any guidance would be very helpful.

Regards,
Sjrjej

Answer (score 1):

To solve you problem, it required some tricky calculation to get the outcome, several steps are needed then you are able to see the expected output, accept if help :)

This is original table

[image]

1. Create a new column combine string from three column using the following formula

   `Person = Sheet1[site]&" "& Sheet1[FirstName]&" "&Sheet1[LastName]`
2. Using count formula to count the number occurrence, if only 1 mean False in your case

   ```
   Duplicate Check = CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[Person]),
                        FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),
                            Sheet1[Person]=EARLIER(Sheet1[Person])))
   ```

3)There is the table with two new column, we are going to filter 1 (False) later
[image]

4. On Power BI visual display, create table report and drag the [Duplicate Check] into filter visual, then uncheck 1, happy ending :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much , that worked !!! Thanks for the detailed solution. It was easy to follow your solution